# javafx auto-imports in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, import, javafx

I installed Netbeans with Javafx. When I create a new JavaFX project, the basic classes needed for the template are automatically imported ( javafx.scene.Scene, javafx.stage.Stage, etc).

When I want to import other javaFX features classes, such as javafx.scene.image.Image, I use the shortcut key combination (ctr + shift + i).

However Netbeans only offers me to autocomplete with java.awt.Image. 
If I start typing "javafx. " and then try to autocomplete (ctrl + space) it does not list anything, the javafx library is not recognized, and I have to manually type the import, even though I created a JavaFX project.

How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem because i have two JDKs in my OS (1.7 and 1.8) and NetBeans selected JDK 1.7 and i change it to JDK 1.8 and my Problem solved

Just Right click on your project -> select Library -> and change java Platform

Comment: You are right, I previously added the JDK7 platform to test compilation under this version. I ust removed it and.., Problem solved, thanks!